# html dropdown menu change dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I have following code. I have  2 select option menu. Every time any of them changed, i want send a AJAX request to a servlet. By using data comes from servlet, i want write it in my html.

How can i do that?

Thanks

```
<div class="p_inforoom">
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${hotelDetail.deal.id}" id="dealId" /> 

    <h3>Oda Bilgileri :<b th:text="${hotelDetail.deal.room.name}"></b></h3>
    <select name="numberOfNights" id="night" onchange="GetNights(this)">
        <option  th:each="rooms:${roomsLeft}" th:text="${rooms}" th:value="${rooms}" id="roomLeft" > </option>

    </select>
    <select name="roomType" id="room" onchange="GetRooms()">
        <option class="1" value="1" >Tek kişilik</option>
        <option class="2" selected="selected" value="2" >Çift kişilik</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `th:value="${hotelDetail.deal.id}"` is neither HTML nor JavaScript, so if this is something like asp or something, please include those tags.

Comment: İT's thymeleaf which takes the objects from servlet and writes it in html. The main goal of Thymeleaf is to provide an elegant and well-formed way of creating templates. Its Standard and SpringStandard dialects allow you to create powerful natural templates, that can be correctly displayed by browsers and therefore work also as static prototypes. You can also extend Thymeleaf by developing your own dialects.

Comment: Okay, good sales pitch, but all I said was to add the tags to your question, so that people know what this question uses before clicking on the question. I've added it for you for now.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the response from the ajax in the "Success", you can read that dataand assign it to whatever html element you want to assign it with

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: requestUrl,
   data: postData, // if any
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) {
      //data has the response from the url
   }
   }});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can do by this

```
$('#room').on('change',function(){
      $.ajax({
          url:"",
          dataType : "",//json text 
          type : "",//get or post
          data:"",
           success:function(data){
         alert(data.output);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for select change:

```
$( "#room" ).change(function() {
alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

[Source for .change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

For Ajax query you can look info at: [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Below you can find one example from that page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
})
```