# Iterate a list based on value selected from dropdown in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf. I have a list called endpointCluster containing String team and List endpoint. 
In the view, I have 2 dropdowns in the view. One is for the team. Another is for endpoints. Now I want endpoint list gets loaded based on the value we have selected for the team.

Here what I have written.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Team</td>
      <td>
         <select id="teamDropdown" required="required" name="team">
            <option th:each="emp: ${endpointsCluster}" th:value="${emp.team}"
               th:text="${emp.team}"></option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">Endpoint Name:</td>
      <td>
         <select id="endppointDropdown" required="required" name="inputJson">
            <option  th:each="endp: ${endpointsCluster[1].endpoints}" th:value="${endp.name}"
               th:text="${endp.name}"></option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here in the endpoint dropdown, I am getting a list of an endpoint for the second element in the endpointsCluster list. 
I want it to dynamically load endpoints based on team value.

Comment: You have to use ajax for that .

Comment: This link will help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917939/dependent-drop-down-list-from-map-in-thymeleaf#answer-35944014

Comment: I think you should change your data structure to a Map here (in your controller you should change your list to a Map). Since you can use a key/value pair more easily with a Map. `HashMap<String, List<Endpoints>> hmap = new HashMap<String, List<Endpoints>>();` Your key is a String which is Team and your value is your Endpoints list for that particular Team. Then iteration over this structure becomes much more easy.