# why select loop in HTML is not working or visible when fetched from AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a JSON data retrieved from Spring boot controller as:

```
    [
    {
        "surgeonId": 13505,
        "surgeonNationalID": 308236823,
        "surgeonFirstName": "Ali",
        "surgeonLastName": "Zah",
        "surgeonNationality": "UK",
        "surgeonDateOfBirth": "1969-03-10T21:00:00.000+00:00",
        "surgeonGender": "Male",
        "surgeonAddress": "322 Diplomatic Dist.",
        "surgeonConact": "02277469",
        "surgeonEmailAddress": "ali@hotmail.com",
        "surgeonSpeciality": "GS",
        "departmentIdInSurgery": 31
    },
    {
        "surgeonId": 13000,
        "surgeonNationalID": 492487233,
        "surgeonFirstName": "Sami",
        "surgeonLastName": "Abdulkareem",
        "surgeonNationality": "Canada",
        "surgeonDateOfBirth": "1960-12-11T21:00:00.000+00:00",
        "surgeonGender": "Male",
        "surgeonAddress": "74 Aiano Dis.",
        "surgeonConact": "02323322",
        "surgeonEmailAddress": "sami@yahoo.com",
        "surgeonSpeciality": "GS",
        "departmentIdInSurgery": 31
    }
]
```

And HTML as:

```
<td>
    <div id="SurgeonId">                        
        <select >
            <option value="" disabled>Select Department First</option>
        </select>                                                       
     </div>                         
</td>
```

And this is the JavaScript code in the HTML page:

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
    function showSurgeons(str) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    
                var ourData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var innerHTMLTest = '<select th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListSurgeonId}"> ';
                for(i=0; i<ourData.length; i++){
                    innerHTMLTest +=' <option th:value="'+ ourData[i].surgeonId + '" th:text="' + ourData[i].surgeonLastName + '">   </option>';
                    console.log('inside loop' + innerHTMLTest);
                }
                innerHTMLTest += ' </select>';
                
                
                console.log(innerHTMLTest);
                alert(document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML);
                document.getElementById("SurgeonId").innerHTML = innerHTMLTest;


            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/surgeon/" + str, false);
        
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

However, I do not get the expected outcome as you can see in the images below:
[image]

The database missing the surgeonId data!

Also, as you can see below, I tried to inspect the code which seems right!

[image]

Thank you for the time spent guys :)

Comment: Thymeleaf tags such as `th:text` and `th:field` don't get parsed when you are running JavaScript (as you can see when you view-source).  If you want your Thymeleaf to be processed it has to be run through your server/controllers.

Comment: Thanx ,,, but would you elaborate ? or give example?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't parsed through the Thymeleaf interpreter.  When you have this code in JavaScript:

```
 '<option th:value="'+ ourData[i].surgeonId + '" th:text="' + ourData[i].surgeonLastName + '">   </option>'
```

The browser sees

```
 <option th:value="13505" th:text="Zah"></option>
```

`th:value` isn't a valid HTML attribute, nor is `th:text`.  Those attributes are only only understood by the Thymeleaf interpreter.  If you want your JavaScript to work, you have to use regular HTML attributes.

```
'<option value="'+ ourData[i].surgeonId + '">' + ourData[i].surgeonLastName + '</option>'
```

Which will output:

```
<option value="13505">Zah</option>
```

You will have to fix  `th:field="${waitinglist.waitingListSurgeonId}"` as well.

Comment: thank you,,, that definitely is gonna help,,, but by then Thymeleaf won't work... I do not want to miss the Thymeleaf ... Is there a way to cast the JavaScrtipt data to make it work with Thymeleaf ?

Comment: Is there a way around to maneuver? or a better idea ?

Comment: Metroids explained it right ..... This code needs to be fixed ! any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Maksim Zagorodsky in his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917939/dependent-drop-down-list-from-map-in-thymeleaf)

I managed to solve it :)

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Procedure Form</title>
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendAjaxRequest() {
        var department = $("#department").val();
        $.get(
                "http://localhost:8080/surgerywaitinglist/getSurgeonsByDep?department="
                        + department, function(data) {
                    $("#surgeonId").empty();
                    data.forEach(function(item, i) {
                        var option = "<option value = " + item + ">" + item
                                + "</option>";
                        $("#surgeonId").append(option);
                    });
                });
    };
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#department").change(function() {
            sendAjaxRequest();
        });
    });
</script>




</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <h3>Add New Procedure</h3>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <form th:action="@{/surgerywaitinglist/saveToWaitinList}" th:object="${waitinglist}"
            method="POST">

            <table class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped"
                id="employeeTable" style="width: 50%" align="center">
                

                <tbody>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Department</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                


                                <select name="departmentName"
                                    th:with="departmentName = ${department.departmentName}"
                                    class="form-control" id="department">

                                    <option value="" th:selected="selected" th:disabled="disabled">select
                                        option</option>
                                    <option th:each="department: ${departments}"
                                        th:value="${department.departmentName}"
                                        th:text="${department.departmentName}"></option>

                                </select>



                            </div>
                        </td>



                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Surgeon</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                


                                <select th:field="${surgeon.surgeonLastName}"
                                    class="form-control" id="surgeonId">
                                </select>

                            </div>



                        </td>


                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>                
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Now I do get the expected outcome as you can see in the images below:

[image]